# How to allow an iframe tag in `dompurify` including all of its attributes

Tags: javascript, dompurify

I want `dompurify` to allow iframe tags, and I add `iframe` as an exception(`ADD_TAGS`). But that removes some attributes of it. I want all attributes to be there.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dompurify/1.0.3/purify.min.js"></script>    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Our DIV to receive content -->
        <div id="sanitized"></div>

        <!-- Now let's sanitize that content -->
        <script>
            /* jshint globalstrict:true, multistr:true */
            /* global DOMPurify */
            'use strict';

            // Specify dirty HTML
            var dirty = '<iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vJG698U2Mvo" width="560"></iframe>';

            var config = { ADD_TAGS: ['iframe'], KEEP_CONTENT: false }

            // Clean HTML string and write into our DIV
            var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty, config);
            console.log('clean: ', clean)
            document.getElementById('sanitized').innerHTML = clean;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the sanitized output

```
"clean: <iframe width='560' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/vJG698U2Mvo' height='315'></iframe>"
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to only allow the iframe tags use ALLOWED_TAGS not ADD_TAGS which allows the default allowed tags and the iframe tag that is not allowed by default.

To allow all default tags and the iframe tag :

```
DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty, { ADD_TAGS: ["iframe"], ADD_ATTR: ['allow', 'allowfullscreen', 'frameborder', 'scrolling'] });
```

To allow only the iframe tag :

```
DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty, { ALLOWED_TAGS: ["iframe"], ADD_ATTR: ['allow', 'allowfullscreen', 'frameborder', 'scrolling'] });
```

Comment: it is still stripping away the various 'src', 'href', 'target' attributes for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the documentation correctly, you also need to register the necessary non-standard attributes that you want to keep using:

```
DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty, { ADD_ATTR: ['allow', 'allowfullscreen', 'frameborder', 'scrolling'] });
```